# Check for item in array without looping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an array and I want to check if one string is in the array, without looping. Just using "if's" I know if some string exists or not in the array.

Is there any possibility?

Comment: Maybe you could put the entire array into a hashmap and just check to see if the element is in the map.

Comment: Actually, @AdamMiller, I'm trying to let it really simple, so if I use hashmap's, I can use "for" loops. Equally, thanks for the help. :-)

Comment: let it really simple... ?

Also, the answer is no, you can't do that without random access for a given key, which would be the string you want to check for. Arrays don't look up an item with a given key, they take an index to offset.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @AdamMiller. I'll try to change my code and find another way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`-[NSArray containsObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a).

(You don't have to write the loop yourself, but of course NSArray almost certainly has to use a loop internally.)

```
if ([array containsObject:string])
    NSLog(@"Yes, the array contains my string.")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kurt. I choose your question for the documentation link. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if ([yourArray containsObject:@"string"]) {

}
```

??

Answer (score 0):

```
NSarray *theArray; // assume exists
if ( [theArray containsObject:someString] )
{
    ...
}
```